# .htaccess simple URL rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is the .htaccess that I have **(updated)**:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteBase / #saw this on many examples online, not sure exactly what purpose it serves

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(\w+.php)$ news.php?post=$2&amp;cat=$1
```

Basically, I want URL's that look like:

- phovze.com/WineGlass/Vin.php
- phovze.com/Chandelier/Auto.php

To be translated to:

- phovze.com/news.php?post=Vin.php&cat=WineGlass
- phovze.com/news.php?post=Auto.php&cat=Chandelier

There is php code to prevent the wrong pages from loading so hopefully using the '*' won't be so risky.

Any idea why this isn't working?

**Edit:**
I changed the line as recommended below to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ./news.php?cat=$1&amp;post=$2
```

This returned a 500 error however, the same post prompted me to add a / because "It starts parsing after the .com" (roughly quoted). This got rid of the 500 error but the site returns 404 still:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ ./news.php?cat=$1&amp;post=$2
```

**edit 2:**
The exact error:
The requested URL /poz/WineGlass/Vin was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried the following as well:

```
RewriteRule ^./poz/(.*)/(.*)$ ./news.php?post=$2&amp;cat=$1
```

poz is the root folder for phovze.com

**edit 3:**
Through persistent web research it appears GoDaddy.com servers require -Multiviews however, even with this disabled, the issue persists.

**Edit 4:**
Used RegExr to verify the regular expression

- http://regexr.com?37s4v **Updated**

It looks as though the server is not seeing that the URL needs to be rewritten and is simply trying to access a file that isn't there. Maybe my expression is incorrect?

Edit 5:
After doing many tests it looks like the server is not identifying that the requested URL needs to be re-written. I have changed the RewriteCond several times to get it to work following the information here:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

However, I have failed to get it to work.

The error that shows the folder /poz/ seems to show up for every 404 so I no longer believe this is the issue. I'm now thinking the issue is that the URL is either not tripping the conditions to be considered for rewriting or the pattern in the expression does not match the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ./news.php?post=$2.php&cat=$1`

I believe having the `phovze.com` part in the rewrite rule is a problem, because the first parameter of the `RewriteRule` only starts matching after the `.com/`

Comment: That "problem" is actually fine because pages with that format won't exist. My question would be surrounding the fact it is a shared hosting and I have 6/7 development sites. If I place the .htaccess in the root of this site exclusively, that won't affect the other sites wil it?

Comment: @Toby .htaccess files only affect the directory it is placed in and its children. It will not affect parent directories.

Comment: Edited question, upvoted for some useful info but question not answered.

Comment: Try it now - I got the order flipped.

Comment: The order won't matter actually, the php script is pretty smart. I tested but it is returning the same error. The server appears to be adding a /poz/ to the url which is the folder the url is hosted in (and the file the .htaccess is in on the server) is there a way to prevent it from adding this?

Comment: There is no .htaccess in any other directory on the server.

Comment: To be clear, you are expecting `phovze.com/news.php` but you are getting `phovze.com/poz/news.php`?

Comment: Updated with the exact error. Yes it appears that might be what it's trying to do. It may also be phovze.com/news.php?cat=poz&amp;post=WineGlass

Comment: Is `/poz/` the root directory (Does phovze.com go to `/poz`)? And is news.php in the same folder?

Comment: Yes to both questions